# Adjusting top banner width of a wordpress site

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I can open the page in Firefox, view the source, and make the changes I want. I don't know how to do these changes in Wordpress. I'm hoping someone could guide me here...

I would like the first highlighted line to change from [ class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4" ] to [ class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-2" ]

I would like the second highlighted line to change from [ col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-8 ] to [ col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-10 ]

These changes are reflected in the before and after screeshot attached.

Theme: Charitize 1.1.5

WP version 5.7.2

[image: Before Image]

[image: After Image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line of code that has what you're looking for is in the function `charitize_header()` in the `\themes\charitize\inc\hooks\header.php` file but you don't want to edit the Parent theme directly.

It is recommended to have a child theme of your parent theme (Charitize) if you want to customize certain aspects or start altering the code. Kinsta has an in-depth guide on creating a child theme here: https://kinsta.com/blog/wordpress-child-theme/#create

You can do this two ways with a Child Theme:

1. The theme developers made it possible for you to override the function by redeclaring it in your child theme's functions.php  `function charitize_header()`, you can copy/paste the function and modify the div classes there.
2. You can override the file by copying it into your child theme using the same filepath as the parent:  `\themes\charitize-child\inc\hooks\header.php`

Both choices will override any future update that Parent theme will get to that function/file, so be aware of that.

Comment: Thank you !  Curious as to why I can't edit directly?

Comment: @MacInnis It is bad practice to edit the parent theme files. For a deeper explanation (since I'm limited to only 500 characters in a comment, sorry!), I recommend you go read the entire article I had linked above in my answer from Kinsta